# li on same line although display:block specified

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-lists

I have some code like this:

```
<div id="sidemenu">
<div id="sidemenuhdr">Beauty Courses</div>
<ul id="sidebarmenu">
<li><a href="#"><b>Professional Skincare & Facials</b></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><b>Spray Tanning</b></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><b>Eyelash Extensions</b></a></li>
<li><a href="electricalfacials.htm"><b>Electrical Facials</b></a></li>
<li><a href="holisticfacials.htm"><b>Holistic Facials</b></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><b>Diamond Peel Microdermabrasion</b></a></li>  
<li><a href="#"><b>Natural Facelift Massage</b></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

With CSS like this:

```
#sidemenu{
width:316px;
float:left;
margin: 5px 10px 5px 0;
background-color:#ffe2d6;
border: 2px solid #3b003b;
display:block;
}

#sidebarmenu{
width:250px;
display:block;
padding:0px; 
margin:2px; 
list-style:none; 
height:20px; 
position:relative; 
z-index:500; 
font-family:arial, verdana, sans-serif;
}

#sidebarmenu li{
float:left; 
}

#sidebarmenu li a{ 
display:block;
height:20px; 
line-height:20px; 
background:none; 
color:#000000; 
text-decoration:none; 
font-size:14px; 
font-weight:bold; 
padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;}
```

Thing is, the result I'm getting is

- Professional Skincare & Facials
- Spray Tanning
- Eyelash Extensions
- Electrical Facials Holistic Facials
- Diamond Peel Microdermabrasion
- Natural Facelift Massage

It is putting Electrical Facials and Holistic Facials on the same line.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please consider the provided answers and accept the one you believe to be the best - some of them do solve this problem as I've tested.

Answer (score 5):

Change #sidebarmenu li to this:

```
#sidebarmenu li{
clear:both;
}
```

That would do the trick!

Answer (score 2):

The `a` elements are `display:block`, but your `li` elements are `float: left`. What exactly do you expect?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is to put in:

```
#sidebarmenu li{
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
```

If you just remove the float, you won't get the pink stretch to the bottom. That's because you've set `height: 20px` on `#sidebarmenu`.

You should consider having as few styles as possible and to separate styling from markup (i.e. don't use `<b>` there, use font-weight.

Answer (score -1):

Just remove `#sidebarmenu li{float:left; }` if you want to li element from top to bottom

Comment: I tryed the same at first but it doesn't work. Need to clear the alignment.